# Quadratic equations in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve this question

If $m$ and $na$ are the roots of an equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and $m+ h$ and $n+h$ are roots of $px^2+qx+r  =0$.

Then prove that

$\frac{b^2 -4ac}{a^2}=\frac{q^2-4pr}{p^2}$

Comment: Where does linear algebra come into play?

Answer (score 0):

That should be $m$ and $n$, not $m$ and $na$. Surely you know of the quadratic formula. Here is a hint: Use the quadratic formula to figure out the distance between the two roots of each equation.